# Boost Installation in CLion

Tags: c++, windows, boost, clion

I am a complete beginner in C++ programming and have been advised to use CLion. I am trying to get the Boost package to work.

I found many posts and tutorials online, however they all skip the basics not known to someone who is not a programmer. Namely, there is no explanation of how to get from the moment you open a new project to using some function from the Boost package?

This is what I found to be lacking from previous answers:

1. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#d93665e349) we are advised to use live incboost live template, however there is no explanation on where to find it or how to use it.
2. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJQ1ybhP7Tw) seems like a clear tutorial, however it is aimed at Visual Studio, not CLion.
3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519453/setup-boost-in-clion) I am not sure what each of those files are and how to adjust them to match my case.

I have downloaded boost_1_70_0 from https://www.boost.org/users/download/ and it is now unzipped and saved in `C:\...\boost_1_70_0`.

Could someone please explain really simply how to get from a blank project to being able to use functions stored in boost?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using CLion and it supports only CMake at this time and you have installed BOOST library in the default directory, then your **CMakeLists.txt** file should look like this. I have used it in linux operating system but it should be able in Windows too.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(LaserCV)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#local
file(GLOB SOURCES
        *.hpp
        *.cpp
        )


add_executable(LaserCV ${SOURCE_FILES} ${SOURCES})
#add_executable(LaserCV main.cpp)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)

#boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(LaserCV ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Then simply include a header file for your wanted boost function, for example:

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
```