# Multiple definion main in boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, libraries, boost-test

I download mingw complier with boost how it was there [Setup Boost in Clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519453/setup-boost-in-clion) Then I started to test my lab and get multiple definition of `main', because my lab has main and C:/MinGw/include/boost/test/impl/unit_test_main.ipp: has main.
 If I commet all my main, tests succesfully passed
And now i can't find solution for my problem.

Comment: A program can only have a single `main` function. What specifically is your problem?

Comment: As @JesperJuhl said, there can be only one main() function in a program. If you want to unit-test what your program does move everything out of the main.cpp into a separate file/module/class, then you test it and call it from your main function.

Comment: Yes, I know. In unit-tests, boost while using file  "unit_test_main.ipp", added main. We can see that in the end of file here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/test/impl/unit_test_main.ipp

Comment: Ok, I got it. I can add in cmakelists main.cpp or test-main.cpp. And now to complie twice to see how programm working and which tests passed or don't passed, Thank you