# How do I Install Boost into CLion?

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to programming in C++ and have heard of the Boost library. I use Clion and i tried following the online tutorials on how to bring boost over to the Clion IDE. I am struggling to understand why I can't extract a Boost 1_75_0.zip file,so im very much stuck on step 1. Really appreciate any help I receive!

What must I learn to be able to install Boost on Clion?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information.  What tutorial are you following?  What are you trying to do to extract the zip file?

Comment: I am using the right-click Extract All... function on the zip file, but it says i have to change the file permissions.

Comment: That probably means you have some permissions problem in your OS. None of this should be done using the "run as administrator" mode of windows. Also you should pick a good place to extract. C:\Program Files or your Desktop folder are both bad places to extract. A better location would be something like `c:\libraries`

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by the mode of windows?,  so I should create a new, empty directory to extract this zip file into?

Comment: You probably want to create a new folder to extract and build boost.

Comment: If you don't know what the "Run As Administrator" is then you probably did not use it.

Comment: ok, i got the zip file extracted into in a new folder called BoostFolder, how did you set it up to CLion?

Comment: After you extract you have to build boost if you need any of the compiled libraries. Although a lot of boost is header only there are parts that need to be built: [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source)

Comment: If you don't want to build it yourself you may want to consult this earlier question if you are using mingw as your compiler and using windows: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519453/setup-boost-in-clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519453/setup-boost-in-clion)